# spring-security-webflux: How to set the realm for BASIC authentication?

Tags: spring-security

I'm just prototyping the migration from Spring MVC to Spring WebFlux using the latest milestone releases (also Spring Boot, Spring Data, and Spring Security). Using the Maven module *spring-security-webflux* I was able to setup *BASIC* authentication. However, I didn't find how to define a realm. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I also couldn't find a way to do it and think it's currently not possible. I've created an issue for it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6270